# Convert a string to a list of floats (in python)

Tags: python

For data storage purposes I am trying to recover lists of floats from a .txt file. From the string like:

`a = '[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]'`

I want to recover:

`a = [1.3, 2.3, 4.5]`

I was expecting a simple solution like `list(a)`, but I cannot find anything like that.

Comment: Look at `ast.literal_eval`. (Must be a dupe).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 3):

Use the **ast module**.

**Ex**

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval('[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]'))
```

**Output:**

```
[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]
```

Comment: Rakesh, bro, do we really need to answer this one? :) (Not the downvoter)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a more manual way:

```
[eval(x) for x in '[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]'.strip("[").strip("]").split(",")]
Out[64]: [1.3, 2.3, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `json`

```
import json
a = '[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]'
json.loads(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you are sure that your input data is of type, a = '[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]'
then you could use the eval command and assign it to same or a different variable.

```
a = '[1.3, 2.3, 4.5]'
b=eval(a)
print(b.__class__)  # to know if b is of type list or not
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a.split(",")
a[0] = a[0][1:]
a[-1] = a[-1][:-1]
a = [float(i) for i in a]
```

This should work :)